# How can I Pass a Custom function from Router, to View, to Template in Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone Router and six Backbone Views which load (depending on User's settings) one of two templates.  Yet, both templates use the same function, and I don't want to repeat myself defining the function in both templates, or in the six Views.  Instead, I would like to define it in the Router.  I know how to pass a model in to a view and template.  But, how can I pass my custom function through to the View and then to the templates so that it can be called in either of them?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a "super" view that all your other views extend.

Something like:

```
var MySuperView = Backbone.View.extend({
  myReusableFunction: function() {
    // do stuff
  }
});

var View1 = MySuperView.extend({});
var View2 = MySuperView.extend({});
```

Both View1 and View2 will have `myReusableFunction` available.

Comment: Hmm.  Interesting suggestion.  I've never nested Views before.  This will help me in a lot of ways other than just the problem listed above.  Thank you eric!